# How to get details of address in Active Directory using UserPrincipal in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal

I am busy with creating a search function into my GUI application who is running on my Windows Server to add, remove, update and search users.
I am almost done building the application, but I can not solve the problem of getting details from an other property which is not given in UserPrincipal like the 'Address' property.
How can I get into that property?

I have tried many coding style to get into the given property 'Address', but it still does not work.

Here is the code:

```
private void ListOfUsers(String ou)
{
    List<string> users = new List<string>();

    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "EMRE", "OU=" + ou + ",dc=emre,dc=han");
    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
    PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);


    foreach (UserPrincipal user in search.FindAll())
    {
        users.Add(user.UserPrincipalName);
        users.Add("********");
        users.Add(user.GivenName);
        users.Add(user.Surname);

        if (user.GetUnderlyingObjectType() == typeof(DirectoryEntry))
        {
            using (var entry = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject())
            {
                if (entry.Properties["Address"] != null)
                    users.Add(entry.Properties["Street"].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
        users.Add(user.VoiceTelephoneNumber);
        users.Add(user.EmailAddress);
        users.Add(ou);

    }

    string[] row = users.ToArray();
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
    lstStudents.Items.Add(listViewItem);

}
```

I always get a null returned even the property is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute you want is actually called [`streetAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-streetaddress). You can also use [`Properties.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.propertycollection.contains?view=netframework-4.8#System_DirectoryServices_PropertyCollection_Contains_System_String_) to check if the value exists (although the effect is really the same as checking for `null`, just easier to read).

```cs
if (entry.Properties.Contains("streetAddress"))
    users.Add(entry.Properties["streetAddress"].Value.ToString());
```

Personally, I like using `DirectoryEntry`/`DirectorySearcher` directly in general, rather than `UserPrincipal`/`PrincipalSearcher` because it gives me more control of what it's doing, which can translate into better performance. I wrote a bit about that here: [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)

Comment: I used to, but after some problems I have got using DirectoryEntry, I changed the method to UserPrincipal

Comment: `UserPrincipal` just uses `DirectoryEntry` in the background, so I'm sure whatever problem you had could have been resolved. But if you have it working now (and performing acceptably), that's all that matters.

Comment: Should I do the same while creating an user? So first I have to create user, save it, then sure for a property called "Address" and then put the details in it?

Comment: Yes, you should use `streetAddress` everywhere. That's the attribute Outlook looks at, and that's the attribute that is changed by the "Street" field on the Address tab in AD Users and Computers.